# Trying to go from 3 grayscale images to one image in RBG

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have 3 images. All of which are grayscale. I want to combine these three images into one, each taking on a single R, G, or B channel.

- Image "Red" becomes the Red channel
- Image "Green" becomes the Green channel
- Image "Blue" becomes the Blue channel

(again images start out in grayscale)

together these should make a single RGB image right? How would I do this in photoshop?
(I'm using Photoshop 2021)

Comment: Copy and paste. You can also show and erase, or multiply and stack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what the "Merge Channels..." feature in the Channels Panel menu is made for.

Open your three grayscale images and select "Merge Channels..." from the Channels Panel Menu:

[image]

Tell it you want to merge an RGB image with 3 channels and click "OK."

Finally, select which of the open files you want to map to each channel:

[image]

Click OK and you have a merged image. No Copy/Paste necessary.

Comment: What you're saying makes sense, however photoshop will not "activate" the merge channels button. I looked further, and if I'm not mistaken all images need to be the same size, so I cropped them down to the same size (only taking off 1 pixel from height), but the merge channels button still doesn't "activate". Here is a link to pictures to show what I mean: https://imgur.com/a/AskmlEN

Comment: @Astro.nor I think it's the transparency. Try flattening the images.

Comment: Perfect! Your help has gotten it to work, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I made myself a script that converts 3 top layers to R, G and B channels, output is the 4th layer below them. Feel free to use/modify.

Input 3 layers for each channel + BG layer:
[image]

Output:
[image]

```js
function main()
{
  var i;
  var channels = ['Rd  ', 'Grn ', 'Bl  '];

  // making 3 top layers invisible
  for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    activeDocument.layers[i].visible = false;
  };
  // select BG layer
  activeDocument.activeLayer = activeDocument.layers[3];

  // applying layers as channels
  for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    selectChannel(channels[i]);
    applyImage(activeDocument.layers[i].name)
  }

  selectChannel('RGB ');

  function selectChannel(id)
  {
    var desc = new ActionDescriptor();
    var ref = new ActionReference();
    ref.putEnumerated(charIDToTypeID('Chnl'), charIDToTypeID('Chnl'), charIDToTypeID(id));
    desc.putReference(charIDToTypeID('null'), ref);
    executeAction(charIDToTypeID('slct'), desc, DialogModes.NO);
  }

  function applyImage(layerName)
  {
    var desc = new ActionDescriptor();
    var descWith = new ActionDescriptor();
    var ref = new ActionReference();
    ref.putEnumerated(charIDToTypeID('Chnl'), charIDToTypeID('Chnl'), charIDToTypeID('RGB '));
    ref.putName(charIDToTypeID('Lyr '), layerName);
    descWith.putReference(charIDToTypeID('T   '), ref);
    descWith.putBoolean(charIDToTypeID('PrsT'), true);
    desc.putObject(charIDToTypeID('With'), charIDToTypeID('Clcl'), descWith);
    executeAction(charIDToTypeID('AppI'), desc, DialogModes.NO);
  }
}

app.activeDocument.suspendHistory("combine to channels", "main()");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it. I assume the three images have the same dimensions.

[image]

- Open the three grayscale images.
- Choose the "Red" image.
- Use *Select > All* (<kbd>Ctrl /Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>) to create a selection that covers the whole image.
- Use *Edit > Copy* (<kbd>Ctrl /Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>) to copy the selection to clipboard.
- Use *File > New* (<kbd>Ctrl / Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>) to create a new document. Photoshop will automatically suggest the dimensions of the selection you just copied. Make sure to set *Color Mode* to *RGB* and select the *Color Profile* you want (probably *sRGB*).
- In the *Channels* panel, click the *Red* channel.
- Use *Edit > Paste* (<kbd>Ctrl /Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>) to paste in the copied image.
- Choose the "Green" image.
- Use *Select > All*.
- Use *Edit > Copy*.
- Choose the RGB image.
- In the *Channels* panel, click the *Green* channel.
- Use *Edit > Paste*.
- Choose the "Blue" image.
- Use *Select > All*.
- Use *Edit > Copy*.
- Choose the RGB image.
- In the *Channels* panel, click the *Blue* channel.
- Use *Edit > Paste*.
- Use *Select > Deselect* (<kbd>Ctrl /Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>) to remove the selection.
- Click the *RGB* channel to show all three channels.
- Optionally use *Image > Adjustments > Invert* (<kbd>Ctrl /Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>) to invert the channels.